# Gtk3 can't scroll ScrolledWindow far enough

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtk3

How can I get a Gtk ScrolledWindow to scroll more than one line's height? (I mean automatically scrolling after I increase the height of the ScrolledWindow's content. Scrolling manually works fine.)

My code writes 3 lines to a Gtk TextView within a Viewport within a ScrolledWindow, and instructs the ScrolledWindow to scroll, but it only scolls downward far enough to reveal the first of the 3 lines.

My ruby code looks like this:

```rb
# Write 3 lines of text
textview.buffer.insert_at_cursor "%s\n"%s\n%s\n % [line1, line2, line3]
# Scroll
textview.scroll_to_iter textview.buffer.end_iter, 0.0, true, 0.5, 0.5 # Scroll to end of Gtk::TextView
vadjustment = textview.parent.parent.vadjustment # Get vadjustment from Gtk::ScrolledWindow
vadjustment.set_value vadjustment.upper
```

I've tried plugging in arbitrary big values into the `vadjustment.set_value` function call, and I've tried various maths with `step_increment` and `page_increment`, but I can't get it to scroll more than one line's height unless I scroll the ScrollView manually. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved scrolling the appropriate amount by moving the scrolling operation into a callback on the "changed" signal:

```rb
buffer = textview.buffer

# Configure scrolling
buffer.signal_connect("changed") {
  mark = buffer.create_mark nil, buffer.start_iter.forward_to_end, false
  textview.scroll_mark_onscreen mark
}

# ...

# Add text to the widget
buffer.insert_markup @output.buffer.end_iter, "\n#{markup}", -1
```